# Why am I switching from controlled to uncontrolled input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm not sure why I'm getting the switch from controlled to uncontrolled input warning. `this.state.lineItemName` is defined in my constructor which seems to be the main mistake from other SO questions I've read.

This is very similar to the [todoMVC](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/react/js/app.jsx) implementation for React.

```
class LineItemForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        newLineItem: ""
      }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}
            value={this.state.newLineItem}
            placeholder="Search for an item..."
            autoFocus={true}
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({newLineItem: event.target.value});
  }

  handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === this.props.ENTER_KEY_CODE || e.keyCode === this.props.TAB_KEY_CODE) {
      e.preventDefault();

      let name = e.target.value.trim();

      if (name) {
        let lineItem = {
          name: name
        };
        this.props.createLineItem(lineItem, this.props.sectionId)
        this.setState({newLineItem: ""})
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
}

LineItemForm.defaultProps = {
    ENTER_KEY_CODE: 13,
    TAB_KEY_CODE: 9
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

`handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({newLineItem: event.target.value});
    }`

instead of

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({newLineItem: event.target.value});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning occurs because of an error in the handler for the `onChange` event.

[Controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) require a handler for the `onChange` event. This allows the component to update its value. If the handler does not work, the `value` cannot be updated via the props and must be set via the value entered by the user.

To fix this error, you'll need to correct the error in the `onChange` event handler you defined:

```
// Parameter was renamed to 'event' to reflect its use in the 
// 'setState' method call below
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({newLineItem: event.target.value});
}
```

Comment: Ah yes e vs. event oops. Thanks